# why is my game so slow in firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, webgl

I was playing around with the new HTML5 standards to see what it can provide and to learn stuff... But I don't get why my game is so slow mosly in firefox.

There is several ways you can choose to "draw" the player and the background.
That can be chosen in bottom right corner.

I have tested the game in **firefox with the result**:

well all in all super slow results. 
With Html it totally lags
with canvas it seems a little better but still totally laggs...

**Google Chrome results:**

Google seems to run the code fairly well... it doenst lagg really.

**Internet Explorer tests**

So here is the interesting part of it all. Internet Explorer 9 runs it super well... its almost too fast on my computer.

So my question is. Does firefox not like my graphic card? or where does it go wrong? maybe my code is too slow? but is i have done the test right it only take aprox 1 ms to run the time interval that redraws the picture (as the timer indicates in top right corner named intervalTimer.

And i would very much like to hear what results u get and if its just firefox hating my graphic card. :-(

Also if u can see where I can do some improvements to make it work better in firefox.

Here is some of my code:

The **interval.js** file runs the setInterval and redraws the player.

```
function interval() {
var startdate = +new Date();  // log start timestamp

if (general_slowmo > 9)
    general_slowmo = 0;
else
    general_slowmo++;

collisions();


if (drawmethod == "canvas") {
    canvas.clearRect(0, 0, general_winwidth, general_winheight);
    drawplayercanvas(p0x, p0y, 0);
}
else if (drawmethod == "html") {
    drawplayerhtml(p0x, p0y, 0);
}
else {
    drawImageWebGl(p0, p0x, (general_winheight - p0y) - general_playerheight);
}


var enddate = +new Date();  // log end timestamp
var diff = enddate - startdate;
$("#intervalTimer").html("intervalTimer: " + diff + "ms");
}
```

but what i get on the intervalTimer div is only 0 or 1 ms time. But i dunno if it counts the time it takes to draw the player?

Inside the interval the function Collisions runs:

```
function collisions() {

var spritex = p0x;
var spritey = p0y;
var jump = jumpp0;
var keyX = keyXp0;
var keyY = keyYp0;
var onground = ongroundp0;

if (keyX == -1) { //left movement
    if (blockexists(spritex - 1, spritey) === false && blockexists(spritex - 1, spritey + general_blocksize) === false) {
        spritex--;
    }
}

if (keyX == 1) { //right movement
    if (blockexists(spritex + general_playerwidth, spritey) === false && blockexists(spritex + general_playerwidth, spritey + general_blocksize) === false) {
        spritex++;
    }
}

if (jump != 0) {
    var aboveone = blockexists(spritex, spritey + (general_playerheight - 1));
    var abovetwo = blockexists((spritex + general_playerwidth - 1), spritey + (general_playerheight - 1));

    if (aboveone === true || abovetwo === true) {
        jump = 0;

        if (toblock(spritex, spritey + (general_playerheight - 1)) == 2) {

            removeblockarray(spritex, spritey + (general_playerheight - 1));

            if (mapdrawmethod == "canvas")
                removeblockcanvas(spritex, spritey + (general_playerheight - 1));
            else
                removeblockhtml(spritex, spritey + (general_playerheight - 1));
        }
        if (toblock((spritex + general_playerwidth - 1), spritey + (general_playerheight - 1)) == 2) {

            removeblockarray((spritex + general_playerwidth - 1), spritey + (general_playerheight - 1));

            if (mapdrawmethod == "canvas")
                removeblockcanvas((spritex + general_playerwidth - 1), spritey + (general_playerheight - 1));
            else
                removeblockhtml((spritex + general_playerwidth - 1), spritey + (general_playerheight - 1));
        }
        spritey--;
    }
    else {
        jump++;
        spritey++;

        if (jump > maxjump) {
            jump = 0;
        }
    }
}

if (keyX != 0 || onground == false) {
    if (blockexists(spritex, spritey - 1) === true || (blockexists(spritex + general_playerwidth - 1, spritey - 1) === true)) {
        if (jump == 0)
            onground = true;
    }

    else if (jump == 0) {
        spritey--;
        onground = false;
    }
}

if (blockexists(spritex, spritey, "item") === true || blockexists(spritex + general_playerwidth - 1, spritey, "item") === true || blockexists(spritex, spritey + general_playerheight, "item") === true || blockexists(spritex + general_playerwidth - 1, spritey + general_playerheight, "item") === true) {

    if (toblock(spritex, spritey) == 11) {
        $("#diamcount").html(++general_numdiamonds);
    }
    else if (toblock(spritex + general_playerwidth - 1, spritey) == 11) {
        $("#diamcount").html(++general_numdiamonds);
    }
    if (toblock(spritex, spritey + general_playerheight) == 11) {
        $("#diamcount").html(++general_numdiamonds);
    }
    else if (toblock(spritex + general_playerwidth - 1, spritey + general_playerheight) == 11) {
        $("#diamcount").html(++general_numdiamonds);
    }

    if (toblock(spritex, spritey) == 10 || toblock(spritex + general_playerwidth - 1, spritey) == 10 || toblock(spritex, spritey + general_playerheight) == 10 || toblock(spritex + general_playerwidth - 1, spritey + general_playerheight) == 10) {
        if (keyY == 1) {
            if (general_slowmo > 5) {
                spritey++;
            }

            onground = true;
            jump = 0;
        }
        if (keyY == -1) {
            if (general_slowmo > 5) {
                spritey--;
            }

            onground = true;
            jump = 0;
        }
    }
}


p0x = spritex;
p0y = spritey;
jumpp0 = jump;
keyXp0 = keyX;
keyYp0 = keyY;
ongroundp0 = onground;
}
```

Anyways what im trying to say is I would like to hear why its so slow. and if you get the same results as me.

Maybe its because i put divs on top of the canvas?

Comment: from my own experience, firefox's canvas implementation has always been a little slower than webkit's or ie's... See this page for example: http://www.gibney.de/firefox_canvas_performance

Comment: ok but in my case its not just a little slower... its super slow :-( In my game that is... Actually trying your link i could not see that big difference than chrome. So maybe its just my game it doesnt like... can i ask, do u get super slow results in my game in firefox?

Comment: Runs fine in Firefox 19 on OS X 10.7.5.

Comment: tried it on chrome & firefox (i'm on linux though) and it seems to run well on both browsers. maybe it's an issue with windows or your own machine?

Comment: Doorknob why u so mad? :-) ;-) thx for testing guys :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm on a Mac OS X 10.8.2 running Firefox 18.0.2 - it actually runs the game faster and smoother than my Chrome 25.0.1364.99. Just by chance, my Firefox just updated to 19.0 and it still seems fine and smooth.

Make sure you are not running any extensions that may conflict with the JS/libraries in your game. Disable all extensions on your Firefox and give it another try - also a [complete reinstall](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Uninstalling_firefox) will help you eliminate a possible cause of the slowness.

Comment: I just tried it on Mac OS X 10.6.8 and Chrome 25.0.1364.99 is definitely faster than Firefox 21.0a2.

Comment: My Chrome has a few extensions installed where as my Firefox is pretty much stock - that could explain why.

Comment: Well... I tried complete reinstall but didnt help. But i guess the conclusion must be that firefox doesnt like my graphic card or something whe gpu accelerating it. I tried to disable hardware acceleration and it actually seemed like it ran a tiny bit faster. Still super laggy though. But thx for help... At least its good to know that you guys can run it...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Firebug` addon it could be the reason.

I had the same problem with my canvas which runs very smoothly on Chrome but very slow and lagging on Firefox. After disabling `firebug` it ran faster on Firefox even faster that it works on Chrome.

hope this helps.